# How to write an if statement that searches for a value within an inherited class?

Tags: java

I'm wiring an assignment that involved inheritance and I am trying to write an if statement that searches if a specific value is true or not. If the value is true to what the if statement is looking for, I want to throw an exception, if it is not I just want to return that value. Here is my code so far:

**Sub class**

```
public class Carnivore extends Animal
{
   public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception
    {
        if (x.equals("Plants")) {
                throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            } else {
                return x;
            }

    }
    public void makeNoise()  
    {
        noise = null;
    }
    public String getNoise()  
    {
        return noise;
    }   
}
```

**Super class**

```
abstract public class Animal 
{

String name;
int age;  
String noise;

abstract public void makeNoise();

public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

abstract public Food eat(Food x) throws Exception;

}
```

The part in which I am stuck on is rephrasing this:

```
if (x.equals("Plants")) {
                throw new Exception("Carnivores only eat meat!");
            } else {
                return x;
            }
```

**Food class**

```
public class Food {

    //field that stores the name of the food
    public String name; 

    //constructor that takes the name of the food as an argument
    public Food(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I want to make it so if the value of x is "Plants" (this is typed in String format) then an exception is thrown else the value is returned. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: to make it a bit more `OOP` i´d include a class `Meat` and a class `Vegetale`, which both inherit from `Food`. Your if condition only has to check `if(x instanceof Meat) {return x} else {...}`

Comment: You need to tell us How your Food class looks like?

Comment: Sorry about that, I've edited the post and added it in.